# Converting an iteration to Async

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asynchronous, asp.net-4.5

I am returning a large number of DataTable rows, iterating them and pushing the values of each row to a webservice, which then returns a response code (string).  Should any errors occur in the webservice, the whole process is stopped and an error shown:

```
Protected Sub DoStuff(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnk_orderCards.Click
    Dim dt as DataTable = GetDataBaseData()
    For each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows()
        Dim f as String = dr.Item("firstname").ToString()
        Dim m as String = dr.Item("middleName").ToString()
        Dim s as String = dr.Item("surname").ToString()
        Dim err as String = String.Empty
        Dim result as String = XYZService.DoIt(f, m, s)
        Select Case result
            Case "ok"
                ' OK - allow For Loop Next '
            Case "e"
                err = "Some error"
            Case "e2"
                err = "Another error"
        End Select
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(err) Then
            ShowError(err)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    XYZService.Complete()
    ltl_status.Text = "Success!"
End Sub
```

I assumed that the above would be a good candidate for an Async approach, especially if the datatable has 1000 rows, as each webservice request could be sent in parallel.  However, from MSDN I can't find enough examples on how best to implement Async.

Can anyone recommend a more thorough approach? I have read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about `Task.WaitAll` and `Task.Factory.StartNew` but the examples aren't straightforward.  If `Task.WaitAll` was utilised [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), how do you stop the flow if one (or more) tasks fail?

It's important that all tasks much return success before `XYZService.Complete()` is called.

**Final code based on Stephen's input**

```
Protected Async Sub DoStuff(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnk_orderCards.Click
    Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataBaseData()
    Dim rows As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of String)) = (From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Select DoServiceCall(cts, dr))
    Dim results() As String = Await Task.WhenAll(rows)
    Dim errors As List(Of String) = (From s As String In results Where s <> String.Empty).ToList()
    If errors.Count > 0 Then
        ShowError(String.Join("<br/>", errors))
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Success")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Async Function DoServiceCall(t As CancellationTokenSource, dr As DataRow) As Task(Of String)
    If t.IsCancellationRequested Then
        t.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    End If
    Dim f As String = dr.Item("firstname").ToString()
    Dim m As String = dr.Item("middleName").ToString()
    Dim s As String = dr.Item("surname").ToString()
    Dim returnResult As XYZService.ServiceReturnResult = Await XYZService.DoItAsync(f, s, s)
    Select Case returnResult.return
        Case "ok"
            ' OK - allow For Loop Next '
        Case Else
            t.Cancel(False)
            Throw New Exception("Web service error: " & returnResult.return)
    End Select
    Return returnResult.return
End Function
```

Comment: async/await will **not** execute anything in parallel. It will, however, allow the GUI to remain responsive while waiting. If you want parallel execution, use `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Then I read that `StartNew` in ASP.Net is *a really bad idea* (http://bit.ly/1ueSZeG) and the alternatives aren't properly documented, and the whole thing just gets even more confusing... :-/

Comment: Fire and forget is a bad idea. If you launch 100 Tasks in parallel _and wait for them_, it's not fire&forget. (It is still a possible DoS because one requests spawns a lot of work)

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster That's not entirely true, while `async` in and of itself doesn't cause methods to magically execute asynchronously, upon hitting the first `await`, code *may* be ran on different synchronisation contexts, and thus, different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `Task.WhenAll`. Specifically, you can project (LINQ's `Select`) each item into a `Task (of T)` and then do an `Await Task.WhenAll`.

However, that simple approach will execute all requests concurrently, and will not stop other requests if one of them failed. That's a bit more complicated; I recommend using a `CancellationTokenSource` to represent the "emergency stop", with each request receiving the `CancellationToken` and cancelling the source if it fails.

Do not use `Task.Run` or its even-worse cousin `StartNew`. Since your operation is asynchronous by nature (an I/O-bound network request), you want asynchronous concurrency (`Task.WhenAll`), not parallel concurrency (`StartNew`).

Comment: First, you'd want to factor out your loop code into a separate method. That will guide you to a better solution. You'll need to pass in the `CancellationTokenSource` and use exceptions for errors instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks again. I've made another revision based on your comment.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes. I would actually pass in the `DataRow` and do *everything* within the `DoServiceCall` method. Then you can pretty easily change the foreach loop into a LINQ `Select` statement.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I have made an *attempt* at this (I'm not strong with LINQ), but would appreciate your guidance on its accuracy/effectiveness please.

Comment: It looks pretty good (but I don't read VB very well). I think you just need to add a check for the cancellation token at the beginning of the `DoServiceCall` method.

Comment: Okay thanks. If that check returns true, what course of action should be taken?  I don't want the calling function to assume that Tasks were successful if `IsCancellationRequested = True`.

Comment: By "check" I actually meant `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: Okay great.  Thank you very much for your help, I've learned a lot.